# How to make the size of two plots equal?

Tags: plotting

I have the following two plots:

```
points = {{91.54444444444445`,99.50517159126667`}, {131.91379310344828`,99.50517159126667`}, {176.5`, 99.50517159126667`}, {192.16666666666666`, 99.50517159126667`}, {158.`, 99.50517159126667`}, {206.5`, 99.50517159126667`}, {426.`, 88.39647641244247`}, {413.`, 86.98937502312475`}, {397.`, 82.84212882303038`}, {413.`, 82.84212882303038`}, {429.`, 82.84212882303038`}, {683.5`, 81.28691149799499`}, {94.5`, 79.5095202693831`}, {110.5`, 79.5095202693831`}}

g2 = ListPlot[points, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "0%"}, {20, "20%"}, {40, "40%"}, {60, "60%"}, {80, "80%"}, {100, "100%"}}, None}, With[{mean1 = 142.565, mean2 = 414.282, 
  mean3 = 685.8}, {{{mean1, 
    Column[{DisplayForm@
       OverscriptBox[Pane["1 - 5", 100, Alignment -> Center], 
        "\[HorizontalLine]"]}], 0}, {mean2, 
    Column[{DisplayForm@
       OverscriptBox[Pane["6 - 10", 100, Alignment -> Center], 
        "\[HorizontalLine]"]}], 0}, {mean3, 
    Column[{DisplayForm@
       OverscriptBox[Pane[">10", 35, Alignment -> Center], 
        "\[HorizontalLine]"]}], 0}}, None}]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
LabelStyle -> {20, GrayLevel[0]}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\[NumberSign] Cities per country"], 
Style["Crimes (% total)"]}]
```

and

```
data = {8.79471, 11.2241, 16.7043, 15.0094, 18.3992, 10.4896, 5.4614, 5.80038, 2.52354, 1.67609, 4.16196}

leftTicks = Table[{i, Row[{i, "%"}]}, {i, Range[5, 20, 5]}]
g1 = BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> Range[1, 10]~Join~{">10"}, 
ChartStyle -> {Red}, BarSpacing -> 0.8, PlotRange -> {0, 20}, 
AspectRatio -> 0.88, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
LabelStyle -> {20, GrayLevel[0]}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\[NumberSign] Cities per country"], 
Style["% Crimes"]}, 
FrameTicks -> {{leftTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]



Grid[{{g1, g2}}]
```

[image]

How can I make the bottom and top of the two plots to be parallel? (And also the horizontal labels.)

Comment: Pleae define `a1,a2,a3` and/or set up a minimal example that plots something. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the same `ImageSize`, `ImagePadding` and `AspectRatio` to both plots.

To deal with your customized $x$-ticks and the position of $x$ label, an easy workaround is to put the labels in a separate row in `Grid`. Manually adjust the number of whitespaces to achive proper centering, relative to the plot.

```
opts = {ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> {{100, 20}, {40, 50}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1};

g1 = BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> Range[1, 10]~Join~{">10"}, 
   ChartStyle -> {Red}, BarSpacing -> 0.8, PlotRange -> {0, 20}, 
   Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> {20, GrayLevel[0]}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"", Style["% Crimes"]}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{leftTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}, opts];


g2 = ListPlot[points, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "0%"}, {20, "20%"}, {40, "40%"}, {60, 
        "60%"}, {80, "80%"}, {100, "100%"}}, None}, 
     With[{mean1 = 142.565, mean2 = 414.282, 
       mean3 = 685.8}, {{{mean1, 
         Column[{DisplayForm@
            OverscriptBox[Pane["1 - 5", 100, Alignment -> Center], 
             "\[HorizontalLine]"]}], 0}, {mean2, 
         Column[{DisplayForm@
            OverscriptBox[Pane["6 - 10", 100, Alignment -> Center], 
             "\[HorizontalLine]"]}], 0}, {mean3, 
         Column[{DisplayForm@
            OverscriptBox[Pane[">10", 35, Alignment -> Center], 
             "\[HorizontalLine]"]}], 0}}, None}]}, 
   LabelStyle -> {20, GrayLevel[0]}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\[NumberSign] Cities per country", 
     Style["Crimes (% total)"]}, opts];


xlabel = Style[Text@"              \[NumberSign] Cities per country", 
   FontSize -> 20];
Grid[{{g1, g2}, {xlabel, xlabel}}]
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: @Marteen, please see my update. I hope this resolves both of your issues.